# Cannot persist record with a Persistent InputStream in OpenJPA

Tags: inputstream, openjpa, persistent

I'm trying to persist a record that has a mapped @Persistent InputStream field.
the context is: JDK 1.8, LiferayPortal on Tomee 1.7.1 (OpenJPA 2.4-patch). Sorry about the stacktrace polluted by the Liferay one.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "file_entries")
public class FileEntry implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 120)
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    @Column(length = 120)
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modified;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;

    @Column(length = 240)
    private String filename;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String extension;

    @Column(length = 20)
    private String version;

    @Column(length = 240)
    private String contentType;

    @Persistent(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private InputStream content;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getExtension() {
        return extension;
    }

    public void setExtension(String extension) {
        this.extension = extension;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public InputStream getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(InputStream content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }
}
```

And when persisting:

```
logo = new FileEntry();
logo.setContent(new FileInputStream("some_local_file"));
entityService.persist(logo);
```

I get the following exception.

```
<openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: The transaction has been rolled back.  See the nested exceptions for details on the errors that occurred.
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newFlushException(BrokerImpl.java:2370)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2207)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2105)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1876)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.flush(DelegatingBroker.java:1045)
        at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:663)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.zeroturnaround.jrebel.integration.openjpa.EntityManagerFactoryWrapper$ReloadingMethodHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryWrapper.java:135)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy619.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.flush(JtaEntityManager.java:202)
        at com.computas.generic.service.SimpleEntityService.persist(SimpleEntityService.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
        at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor585.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:308)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:303)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:308)
        ... 171 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.0-nonfinal-1598334-r422266:1599166 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: can't call setAutoCommit when the connection is JtaManaged
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4998)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4958)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:134)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:108)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:60)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.populateRowManager(AbstractUpdateManager.java:185)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:96)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:77)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:732)
        at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
        ... 204 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: can't call setAutoCommit when the connection is JtaManaged
        at org.apache.openejb.resource.jdbc.managed.local.ManagedConnection.forbiddenCall(ManagedConnection.java:185)
        at org.apache.openejb.resource.jdbc.managed.local.ManagedConnection.invokeUnderTransaction(ManagedConnection.java:162)
        at org.apache.openejb.resource.jdbc.managed.local.ManagedConnection.invoke(ManagedConnection.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy618.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:167)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:167)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.ConfiguringConnectionDecorator$ConfiguringConnection.setAutoCommit(ConfiguringConnectionDecorator.java:117)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:167)
        at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:167)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary.insertPostgresBlob(PostgresDictionary.java:627)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.PostgresDictionary.insertBlobForStreamingLoad(PostgresDictionary.java:614)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.LobFieldStrategy.insert(LobFieldStrategy.java:100)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.insert(FieldMapping.java:623)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.insert(AbstractUpdateManager.java:238)
        at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.populateRowManager(AbstractUpdateManager.java:165)
        ... 208 more
```

The persistence unit declaration is:

```
<persistence-unit name="uefiscdi" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <jta-data-source>uefiscdiDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="postgres" />
        <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=INFO, Tool=INFO" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The Datasource declaration is:

```
<Resource id="uefiscdiDS" type="DataSource">
    JdbcDriver          org.postgresql.Driver
    JdbcUrl             jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name
    UserName            user_name
    Password            user_password
    JtaManaged          true
    DefaultAutoCommit   false
</Resource>
```

I tried with DefaultAutoCommit true / false / not declared ... same exception.

Comment: Can we also see the contents of your persistence.xml?

Comment: Updated the original posting with persistence.xml , tomee.xml and additional information

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried calling `em.persist(...)` rather than `em.merge(..)`?

If that doesn't work it might be helpful if you posted the full stack trace somewhere. I'm afraid you might have snipped off the important parts.

Comment: I have corrected the stacktrace to show the relevant portion I obtained after wrapping all persistence related methods from my ejb in "em.flush()" calls, just in order to avoid the original exception being swallowed by OpenEjb.